# Android Screen Shot

Tags: android

While I try to take a screen shot in C:\android-sdk_r08-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools
\ddms, if I click this ddms I get the error: Failed to get adb version, Cannot run adb...

Comment: Are you using Eclipse with the Android pluggin as your IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse then just click on DDMS and go to device tab in which there is a facility to capture a screen shot